# Why is predict_on_batch is repeating the first output over and over?

Tags: python, tensorflow, replit

I honestly don't know how to describe my problem. Basically, it only uses the first values in my tables and repeats it over and over for the rest of the values in the table. Like I said, just look at the output.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 0, 0],     #x1
              [1, 0.5, 0],   #x2
              [1, 1, 0],   #x3
              [0.5, 1, 0],   #x4
              [0, 1, 0],     #x5
              [0, 1, 0.5],   #x6
              [0, 1, 1],   #x7
              [0, 0.5, 1],   #x8
              [0, 0, 1],     #x9
              [0.5, 0, 1],   #x10
              [1, 0, 1],   #x11
              [1, 0, 1]]) #x12
#Key:
#[red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple]
y = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],  #y1
              [0,1,0,0,0,0],  #y2
              [0,0,1,0,0,0],  #y3
              [0,0,0,1,0,0],  #y4
              [0,0,0,1,0,0],  #y5
              [0,0,0,1,0,0],  #y6
              [0,0,0,0,1,0],  #y7
              [0,0,0,0,1,0],  #y8
              [0,0,0,0,1,0],  #y9
              [0,0,0,0,0,1],  #y10
              [0,0,0,0,0,1],  #y11
              [1,0,0,0,0,0]]) #y12

# Define the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))

# Compile the model
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1), "BinaryCrossentropy", metrics=[ 'binary_accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=500)

predictions = model.predict_on_batch(x)
print(predictions)
```

Here is the output:

```
[[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]
[0.16287932 0.07145664 0.08749434 0.26094046 0.25779992 0.16714773]]
```

Here is the link to the Replit cover page for more details:
https://replit.com/@EthanKantala/Color-Guesser-Tensorflow?v=1

I have tried adding more neurons and doing some research. I honestly have no idea what to do. Thanks for any help!

Comment: A good advice when working with neural networks is generally to not add so many layers right away, but experiment with shallower model and then add layers once you see that you reached the capacity. In this case you would be likely to overfit on this task using such a deep model.

Comment: I also tried it with 5 layers but it still has the same problem. In the output each line should have different values but they are all the same. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: 5 layers is probably already too much for this kind of dataset. You have 12 records in your training. There's some advice on how much should be the network for a particular dataset size https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257292/minimum-training-size-for-simple-neural-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted two problems with your code.
First of all, the alias of [Binary Cross Entropy loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) is `binary_crossentropy` so I got an error running your code on my machine.

Second thing. If you reduce your layers definition to

```
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
```

Then it should work, at least on my machine it did. But also because you are training for 500 on such a small dataset with such a deep network and then predicting the same dataset, what you will get is actually almost complete memorisation of this dataset.

Comment: As per, why the input is always the same, I can't tell on the spot, but my hypothesis would be that the network is so deep that such a small signal just gets lost inside of it when you train in on such a small dataset.

Comment: It worked, but im wondering my it puts the outputs into scientific notation. Heres an example: 9.86040711e-01 Also, how can you make an estimate on how big the model needs to be. Also, thanks for the help!